# Open a terminal a run a program on it automatically when the session starts

Tags: 12.04, command-line, scripts

I have a script to open a terminal and run a command on it:

```
#!/bin/bash
export DISPLAY=:0.0
/usr/bin/gnome-terminal -e '/home/me/bin/application --option a --option b --debug'
```

However, the gnome-terminal appears in a blink and then this disappears when the script is executed for the startup application service. I want to leave this terminal open because this gives basic information in the debugging mode.
When I run this basic script in a terminal, all is fine. This only fails as this is executed for the startup application service.

Any suggestions?

**Update**

OK, I edited the profile preference in gnome-terminal not to close the terminal, once the program has been executed *(profile preferences->Title and Commands -> in When command exits->Hold the terminal open)*. I could read a message in the terminal that says during the execution of the script hasn't been found certain python libraries. By the way, the program that I want to run is a python script. Obviously, at the beginning of the python script, I put:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Even so, It is not working. I usually put certain environmental variables in the ~/.bashrc script to be called when a gnome-terminal is open. How can I source the ~/.bashrc script using /bin/sh?

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this, I believe, with the "sleep" command: `sleep [number]` (essentially makes the terminal wait for however many seconds you put in the number field... i.e. `sleep 100` would make it wait 100 seconds before closing. You could quit the terminal at any time, as well.